# How to load the values instead of Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table :

If there's just one `'Zero'` in between the values of the power_output then i need to check if the absolute average value is `less than 5%` of the absolute average value `(0.05*absolute average value)`.

If that's the case, we need to change the value of zero to average value of the previous row value.

If the value of the power_output gradually drops, I need to check if the value is `greater than 0.25*Name_plate`.

If that's the case, I need to update the previous row value.

```
Sitename   |date&time   |Power_output   |Name_Plate| 

ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 02:00:00.000   |196.852984494331   |100

ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 02:00:00.000   |196.860450855433   |200

xyz0001   |2013-07-21 02:00:00.000    |196.852984494331   | 100

xwz0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.860450855433 || 200

xyq0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.958395639561 || 100

xys0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.045580192147 || 150

xyd0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.089550181982 || 100

xye0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.20098185022  || 200

xyg0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 0        || 200

cfg0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.412144323522 || 200

acb0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.852984494331 || 100

bdf0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.860450855433 || 150

olk0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.886233049016 || 100

ujh0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 0        || 100

iop0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.852984494331 || 100

qrw0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.852984494331 || 100

kml0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.852984494331 || 100

abc0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 196.852984494331 || 100

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 18:00:00.000 ||  197.161464379509|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 19:00:00.000 ||  197.203924005547|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 20:00:00.000 ||  197.109157360779|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 21:00:00.000 ||  197.062176347927|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 22:00:00.000 ||  196.933951782133|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-08 23:00:00.000 ||  196.720954466091|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 00:00:00.000 ||  53.4555526290512|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 01:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 02:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 03:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 04:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 05:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 06:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 07:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 08:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 09:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 10:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 11:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 12:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 13:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 14:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 15:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 16:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 17:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 18:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 19:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 20:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 21:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 22:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-09 23:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 01:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 02:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 03:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 04:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 05:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 06:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 07:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 08:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 09:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 10:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 11:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 12:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 13:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200 

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 14:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 15:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 16:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 17:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 18:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 19:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 20:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 21:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 22:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-10 23:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 00:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 01:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 02:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 03:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 04:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 05:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 06:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 07:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 08:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 09:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 10:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 11:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 12:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 13:00:00.000 ||  0       || 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 14:00:00.000 ||  69.2397589844922|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 15:00:00.000 ||  129.878528692876|| 200

ACT0001   ||2013-07-11 16:00:00.000 ||  129.946054198695|| 200
```

one part of the output should look like this(This is when their are no consecutive Zero's)

*xyd0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.089550181982 || 100

```
xye0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.20098185022  || 200

xyg0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 ||197.20098185022   || 200

cfg0001   ||2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 || 197.412144323522 || 200*
```

- if their are consecutive Zero's and their is a drop in the Power_output column then i need to calculate the output absolute average value of the rows(previous value to the Zero and value after zero(NOT NULL VALUES))  in Power_output column and compare it with the 0.05* Absolute average value,

if the answer is less 5% of the( 0.05* Absolute average value) then i need to copy the previous value to zero into the NULL columns.

if the answer is more 5% of the( 0.05* Absolute average value) then i need to retain the zero value.

Comment: post actual table structure here not image

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: So now we know something about what you need to do. Do you also have a question ?

Comment: I am new to SQL.  how should i write a code for this type of problem? can some one help me out in this.   i am using sql 2010 server.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the desired result in it also. That would make it much clearer to know what you need